# Best way to implement case-insensitive queries in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

What is the best way to implement case-insensitive queries in MongoDB?

For example, 
A database has a collection of contacts with a first name field.
One document has 'Adam' in the first name field, another has 'adam'.
What is the best way to query for documents with the first name = 'adam', regardless of the case?

Answer (score 9):

[Regex](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) is your best bet:

```
db.collection.find({name: /^adam$/i})
```

If you're pre-3.2 then you'll need to use the `$regex` operator:

```
db.collection.find({name: { $regex: /^adam$/, $options: 'i'}})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.contacts.find({firstName: /^adam$/i })
```